# Assembly exact location of esp

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly

In a compiled code by an unknown compiler, I have found the following code:

```
fld qword ptr [esp+10h]
```

at the moment this line is running, there are two values in the stack after `ebp` and local variables/arguments (function is followed by `sub esp,000000A0h`).

```
stack: 3.0, 4.4 (top of stack)
```

My confusion is that what number is loaded by `[esp+10h]`? does it refer to `3.0` or a value before `3.0` which does not make sense here?

Comment: `esp +10h` would be 16 bytes from the top of stack, meaning the 3rd double down. Unless these are parameters, and there is also a return address on the stack?

Comment: @BoPersson thanks for your hint. Is `esp+10h` in the middle of function the same as `esp+10h` after several stuffs were pushed into stack?

Comment: It depends on *where* they are pushed. The value of `esp` changes when you `push` and `pop`, as well as for `call` and `ret`.

Comment: @BoPersson thank you very much. was very helpful